# Unhandled exception runtime error using Throw and Catch

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

So I think I understand Throw and Catch but I'm not sure. I am using it to catch divide by zero error and have looked at other examples online but every time I try mine it throws an unhandeled exception error. I use the throw function in the constructor as required by my assignment and then try and catch it in int main. Does anyone know why I am getting this runtime error about unhandled exceptions?
**Constructor**

```
Rational(int n, int d)
{       
    num = n;
    denom = d;
    normalize();

    if (d == 0) {
        throw "Divide by Zero";     
    }       
}
```

**Int Main() code**

```
int main()
{
int case_count, a, b, c, d;
cin >> case_count;

for (int i = 0; i < case_count; ++i) {
    cout << "Case " << i << "\n";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    cin >> d;
    Rational frac1(a, b);
    Rational frac2(c, d);
    Rational add;
    Rational sub;
    Rational mult;
    Rational div;

    try {
        add = frac1 + frac2;
        sub = frac1 - frac2;
        mult = frac1 * frac2;
        div = frac1 / frac2;


    }
    catch (const char* msg) {
        cout << msg;

    }
    cout << add << " ";
    cout << sub << " ";
    cout << mult << " ";
    cout << div << " ";
    cout << (frac1 < frac2) << "\n";
    cout << frac1.toDecimal() << " ";
    cout << frac2.toDecimal() << "\n";

}
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Rational` constructor throws the exception, so, Rational objects creation must be done within the `try` statement. You are creating many objects outside this statement, so any exception thrown here is unhandled.

You need to create the objects within the try statement. Also, as commented in you OP, you need to handle the exception in a better way:

```
Rational::Rational(int n, int d)
{       
    num = n;
    denom = d;
    normalize();

    if (d == 0) {
        throw std::overflow_error("Divide by zero exception");
    }       
}
```

And then do:

```
try {
    Rational frac1(a, b);
    Rational frac2(c, d);
    Rational add;
    Rational sub;
    Rational mult;
    Rational div;

    add = frac1 + frac2;
    sub = frac1 - frac2;
    mult = frac1 * frac2;
    div = frac1 / frac2;
}
catch (std::overflow_error e) {
    cout << e.what();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You throw the exception in your constructor, specifically the one that takes two `int`s. Therefore you must put that code in the try block.

E.g.

```
try {
    Rational frac1(a, b);
}
catch (const char* msg) {
    cout << msg;

}
```